# .map file poiting wrong lines after LESS -> CSS compilation

Tags: css, less

I used WinLESS but there is no option to support `.map` file in version 1.x and version 2.x is not fully functional, so I decided to use Koala instead.

I downloaded latest version of Koala and I have problem with LESS compiler. After compilation `.map` links my styles to completely different places in LESS files than it suppose to.

I am using Chrome developer tools to debug CSS with mapping option on.

I am importing a lot of modules to my main file which looks like below:

```
@import 'modules/general.less';
@import 'modules/icons.less';
@import 'modules/faq.less';
@import 'modules/confirmation.less';
@import 'modules/customization.less';
@import 'modules/radios_and_checkboxes
...
```

The results of `.map` links to different places depends if I select minified version of output or normal, however in both cases it indicate's wrong lines.
Is there any setup that I may missed?

Comment: You may want to also file an issue on the GitHub issue tracker for the Koala project. https://github.com/oklai/koala/issues

Comment: @CodingWithSpike I did, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally I realized that issue happen only if I have turn on auto prefixes. 
What Koala probably does is compile less first, create .map file and then add prefixes what obviously will change the lines which should be indicated by .map. Unfortunately only solution to fix that is add prefixes in you less files.

Comment: Just in case, Autoprefixer supports passing sourcemaps through with corresponding corrections (so yes, it's definitely makes sense to raise a bug report at the Koala repo).